# SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor throwing NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, maven, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm trying to autowire beans to EJBs with Spring using the `@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)` annotation. The problem is that I keep on getting the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` for the autowired classes when the EJBs are instantiated. (The Filter class in my example).

I'm using Java EE 6 application (EJB 3.0), Spring 4.2.2 managed with Maven and running in a WebSphere 7 AS.

I have the following Spring dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Implementation:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(ServiceRemote.class)
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class Service implements ServiceRemote {

@Autowired
private Filter filter;

...

}
```

Class to be autowired

```
@Component
public class FilterImpl implements Filter { ... }
```

The beanRefContext.xml which `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor` will look for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="businessBeanFactory"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath*:applicaion-context.xml" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The application-context.xml with the bean definitions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <bean class="com.FilterImpl" />

</beans>
```

Both XMLs are in the classpath, as they are in src/main/resources/.

I've tried some debugging with the following code, but couldn't find something useful.

```
BeanFactoryLocator factoryLocator = ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.getInstance("classpath:beanRefContext.xml");

BeanFactoryReference ref = factoryLocator.useBeanFactory("businessBeanFactory");
BeanFactory factory = ref.getFactory();

FilterImpl instance = factory.getBean(FilterImpl.class);
```

Both contexts appear to be loaded, as I get logs like the following, when the EJB is instantiated for the first time.

```
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@7730773; root of context hierarchy
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/C:/project/service-module/target/classes/beanRefContext.xml]
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@5580558: root of context hierarchy
```

But after that Spring can't find the bean I defined in the `application-context.xml`.

In `application-context.xml` I've tried using `<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>` instead of the `<bean class="com.FilterImpl" />`, but I got the same result.

Am I missing some configuration?

**Edits: Added suggestion by Steve C and logs of context loading.**

Comment: Is this an EJB jar? Or a web application (WAR)?

Comment: I have already answered it, but I can only flag it as the correct one tomorrow. Thanks for your help @SteveC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the answer. In the `<constructor-arg value="classpath*:applicaion-context.xml" />` there is an `applicaion-context.xml` when it should be `application-context.xml`. When I edited the question and posted the logs about the loading of the contexts, I noticed that only `beanRefContext.xml` had its definition loaded. There was no logs about some parsing error and I just ignored this possibility. Everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Move your xml configuration files from `src/main/java` to `src/main/resources`.

Files in `src/main/java` are only processed by the maven-compiler-plugin.

Additional resource files are processed by the maven-resources-plugin which copies files from `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Just did that, but nothing changed. I'll edit the question with the new config location.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not adding `<context:annotation-config/>` in your spring xml file